# How to get default values of table properties in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created an internal table using HiveQL:

```
CREATE TABLE city (
  id INT,
  city VARCHAR(15)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Inserted one record

```
INSERT INTO city SELECT 1, null;
```

I want to know which default values are used. But Hive returns 'Table default.city does not have property'

```
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES city('serialization.format');
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES city('serialization.null.format');
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES city('serialization.encoding');
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES city('serialization.escape.crlf');
```

I also don't see them using the describe command:

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED city;
```

I found out which values are used analyzing files on HDFS but I want to know if there is any easy way to get default values using HiveQL.